# Aeson: "when expecting a string, encountered an object instead"

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I'm fairly new to Haskell, so I meant be missing something simple. Right now, I'm just trying to read in some JSON from stdin and get the AST back as a proof of concept.

```hs
module JSONStuff where

import qualified Data.Aeson as JSON
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as Char

main :: IO ()
main = do
    input <- Char.getContents
    case JSON.eitherDecode input of
        Left err -> putStrLn $ "Bad JSON: " ++ err
        Right value -> do
            putStrLn "Got:"
            putStrLn value
```

I have this JSON fragment (which JSONLint says is ok):

```
{
  "foo": 123
}
```

When I the program with that input, I get:

```
$ cat examples/object.json | runhaskell Main.hs
Bad JSON: when expecting a String, encountered Object instead
```

When I test on a file that's and empty array, it says it "encountered Array instead".

So I'm guessing I'm missing some kind of conversion step in here, or I'm reading from stdin incorrectly. What do you think?

Comment: I inserted your code into SO's markup.  You can hit "edit" on your post to see an example of how to do it.  SO uses 4 spaces before each line of code (much like markdown) to indicate code.  You can optionally add a `<!-- language: lang -->` tag before the code to specify which syntax highlighting to use.  It guesses that your code should be highlighted with whatever your main tag is, so if you're posting to the haskell tag, it will assume Haskell syntax.

Comment: Thanks! Figured it wasn't too complicated, but I had to run and didn't want someone to say "well, your code doesn't compile, so there's the problem". :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
putStrLn value
```

Since the type of `putStrLn` is `String -> IO ()`, the type of `value` is inferred as `String`, so the `FromJSON` instance for strings will be used, which will only decode strings, since that's what the type can handle. To decode something else, you need a different type for `value`.

Try

```
print (value :: JSON.Object)
```

if you expect an object, or

```
print (value :: JSON.Value)
```

if any JSON value is acceptable.

Note the use of `print` instead of `putStrLn`. `print` accepts any type with a `Show` instance, so unlike `putStrLn` it does not force its argument to be a string. Also note that `print value` without the type annotation would not work in this example, as there would not be enough information for the compiler to deduce which type `value` should have, and therefore which `Show` and `FromJSON` instances to use.

Comment: Ah, ok--makes sense. It looks like I also could've done `putStrLn $ show value` (although I get a lint warning). Is this more idiomatic?

Comment: [That's how `print` is defined](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/src/System-IO.html#print), so it's more idiomatic to use `print`.